# How to put layout_as_tree in VisIGraph function with a specific root node in R?

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

I am trying to plot an igraph object using the visIgraph function in R, this function has a parameter layout which takes a string input. However, I want a layout_as_tree with a specific root node like how it's possible while plotting on igraph.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any data to plot, so I will make a simple tree as an illustration.

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

## Basic tree
EL = matrix(c(1,2,1,3,2,4,2,5,3,6,3,7), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2)
Tree = graph_from_edgelist(EL)
```

There are two ways that you can use the `igraph` layouts to plot using `visIgraph`.

#### 1 Pass in the layout function to be used

```
visIgraph(igrap=Tree, layout="layout_as_tree", flip.y=FALSE, root=1)
```

The extra arguments `flip.y=FALSE, root=1` are passed to the function `layout_as_tree`.

#### 2 Create the layout first and pass the layout matrix to `visIgraph`

This version allows you to look at the layout and adjust it if you want.

```
LO = layout_as_tree(Tree, root =1, flip.y=FALSE)
visIgraph(Tree, layout='layout.norm', layoutMatrix=LO)
```

Both versions create this graph.

[image: Tree Diagram]

### Edit - Responding to comment on 100 nodes

Of course, you can only show so many nodes on the screen and still see what is going on, but at 100 nodes I got pretty good results by using `type="full"`.

```
T100 = make_tree(100)
LO = layout_as_tree(T100, root =1, flip.y=FALSE)
visIgraph(T100, type="full", layout='layout.norm', layoutMatrix=LO)
```

[image: 100 Nodes]

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked. This is an unrelated question, my node labels and sizes are really small when I plot it and some nodes are cluttered together. VisIgraph allows me to manually move and zoom in once plotted, but is it possible to space the vertices and increase the size when it is being plotted? I have tried increasing the size, but that didn't work. Also my edges are being colored even though I haven't given any edge color property. Could you help me with this? I would post a pic of the graph I am getting but I am new to stack overflow and I am not sure as to how to do it. @G5W

Comment: @Dwarkesh23  So that I have an idea of what you need,   how many nodes do you have?

Comment: do you have any solution for 100 nodes? or should I reduce the number of nodes?

Comment: Adding to answer WRT 100 nodes

Comment: I have one more question regarding Igraph. I have asked it as a separate question. Could you have a look at it if possible?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759159/how-to-select-only-those-vertices-which-are-neighbors-of-set-of-vertices-in-r-us

Comment: Is it possible to rotate the tree counterclockwise by 90 degrees?